# apache rewrite module not transferring $_GET array

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use a simple URL Rewrite in my application.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^show/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /show.php?d=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^sitemap/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /sitemap.php?d=$1
RewriteRule ^sitemap/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /sitemap.php?d=$1&page=$2
```

All of them redirects fine but the problem is with the url parameters they are not transferred in the process.

i.e, I get to `example.com/show/district/id` but the script acts as if it went to `example.com/show.php`. I used `var_dump()` in php to debug and `var_dump($_GET)` returned an empty array.

**NOTE : I am new to htaccess and url rewriting, so couldn't actually find my answer from any other questions please help.**

Comment: `example.com/district/id` will not match any of your rules. Is it perhaps a typo?

Comment: @Mike Anthony It was a typo, can you help me with this I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the modified code below:

```htaccess
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^show/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ show.php?d=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sitemap/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ sitemap.php?d=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sitemap/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ sitemap.php?d=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

**A note on MultiViews:**

If you don't use `-MultiViews`, the server automatically assumes that you're trying to run `show.php` directly, because it looks for `show.*`. It knows that the file `show` does not exist, and therefore will search for a file that has `show` at the beginning.

See [this document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) for more information.

Comment: Are you using your own scripts, or a framework? I'm wondering if the `$_GET` array has been emptied on purpose, in order for it to be accessed using another function.

Comment: And, is your site live? If this is at all possible, I'd like to take a look at it.

Comment: have you ever heard about such a problem, or will it be a problem with the mod_rewrite module configuration. All the rules works just fine with my local server with apache 2.2.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your rewrites. I think the problem may be coming from a script. I could be wrong, however. I might be missing something.

Comment: Can you post your entire `.htaccess`, if what you have above isn't all of it?

Comment: the site url is keralaoffices.com/show/malappuram/1 but this works : http://www.keralaoffices.com/show.php?d=Malappuram&id=1

Comment: not much in my htaccess file here: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^show/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ show.php?d=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ sitemap.php?d=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ sitemap.php?d=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Comment: the 404 is generated by my script when the `$_GET` array `id` and `d` are not provided

Comment: `httpd.conf` ? Correct me if I am wrong isn't that in the server folder. I don't do much edits in that.

Comment: It would be in your server folder. But leave that now, because it isn't what is causing it. Let me research further.

Comment: Please see my amended answer. I have added the `QSA` flag to each rule.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But unfortunately that doesn't do it either. If you get any idea please reply. What makes me mad is that it worked fine on my testing environment.

Comment: if you use `var_dump($_REQUEST);`, what is the output?

Comment: i just installed wordpress and the url redirection in it works fine. Here's it's htaccess `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: I think that your PHP scripts are somehow emptying the `$_GET` array. If that isn't the case, then I honestly don't know what to do.

Comment: Quickly try adding `Options -MultiViews` to your file, above `RewriteEngine On`...

Comment: If it works, I'll add it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: Have updated my answer again. Please try with that code. If that doesn't work, it is definitely your framework/scripts that is emptying the array.

Comment: Mike's my guy!!!! for today at least... Thanks a ton! That works like a charm. Tell me why it worked if you can. Add it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll be happy if you can explain it. So that I won't make that mistake again. Thanks anyway. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: If you don't use `-MultiViews`, the server automatically assumes that you're trying to run `show.php` directly, because it looks for `show.*`. See [this document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) for more information.

Comment: Also, note that you should get your PHP script to allow `malappuram` as well as `Malappuram`. Note the capital 'M'.